# Comparing more than two proportions within one sample

Tags: binary-data, proportion

My experiment was in short: I had less than thirty individuals. One individual had to choose between three colours (green/red/yellow). (Very much like a multiple choice.)

Now, my question is how do I show that significantly more individuals chose red than green or yellow? Can I go with a binary test (one sample, one event) and test for one combination at the time (% that chose green vs % that chose red;  % that chose green vs % that chose yellow;  % that chose red vs % that chose yellow)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to estimate the multinomial probability of an individual choosing each color and estimate confidence intervals.  An easy way to do this in R would be with the `MultinomialCI` package.

```
library(MultinomialCI)
dat <- data.frame(color = c("Green","Red","Blue"), count = c(15, 7, 8))
CI <- multinomialCI(dat$count, alpha = 0.05)
dimnames(CI) <- list(dat$color, c("Lower","Upper"))
print(CI)
```

If the confidence intervals do not overlap, you have a significant difference at the given $\alpha$.  If you have individual-level covariates that may influence the selected group, you could use a more complicated method, like a multinomial logistic regression.

Comment: How would you report these results in a paper?